# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in this code

Tags: javascript

I don't know why the script doesn't recognize the `body`.

My HTML with the script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
        </script>
    <body>
    <table width="2000px" height="1000px">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element?rq=1

Comment: Please re-write your question in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.body` is `null` because your code runs as soon as the `script` tag is encountered, and `body` hasn't been created yet.

Move your `script` to the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag.

---

That said, there's no need for JavaScript here. You can simply add a CSS style:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

...or an inline `style` attribute on the opening `body` tag:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
```

Comment: Yes thanks, i know that but i need to do in js, i fix this as you say it or with 'window.onload'

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <table width="2000px" height="1000px">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
    </script>
</body>
```

You just have to put your script tag before body ends. right now your script tag gets executed before body tag loads.